# Why does one form disappear from Alt-Tab list and the other doesn't?

Tags: c#, winforms, alt-tab

I'm trying to find a way to hide the main form of my app from Alt-Tab list after minimizing it. So far I found that setting form style to `SizableToolWindow` does the trick, but this seems like an improper solution.

I have two winform apps. One of them is supposed to only have tray icon visible, but it still has the main form. Alt-Tab visibility problem is resolved there by doing `this.Hide()` in `Form_Shown` method. The other app does not have `Form_Shown`, but it has `Form1_SizeChanged` method with code:

```
this.Hide();
this.ShowInTaskbar = false;
```

…and for some reason it does not result in the same as the first app. I could only hide it from Alt-Tab list by also setting the main form's style to `SizableToolWindow`. While it's working, I'd like to know why the supposedly proper approach does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting `this.ShowInTaskbar = false`  before `this.Hide()` should hide the form from Alt-Tab list. Apparently, you have to set the visibility option before hiding the form, or it will not hide the window from Alt-Tab. With this there is no need to set the form style to `ToolWindow`. As for the "why", I have no idea.